# Format string displayed in a label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, xcode, xcode4

I'm creating a small iPhone calculator and I have done the usual operations but the only problem that I have is that my digits are displayed with a decimal point and six zeros after it. So when I press the button with the tag 5 this is displayed on the display label

```
---------------
|     5.000000|
---------------
```

I only one to see number 5 without the zeros. Any suggestions?

This is the code that I have that display the digits pressed on the display label:

```
- (IBAction)digitAction:(id)sender {
    currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (double)[sender tag];
    display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2f",currentNumber];
}
```

I have tried the following methods to format the string but it doesn't seem to work:

Instead of: `@"%2f"` I have tried `@"%f"`, `@"%d"` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to an integer!

```
display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentNumber] intValue]];
```

Tada!

Although, it would be more efficient to use an integer from the beginning:

```
int currentNumber = 5;
display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentNumber];
```

But, this does not allow you to do `float division`; if this is a required element of your code, use the first option.

Comment: (int)currentNumber would do just fine, no need to build up an NSNumber just for that.

Comment: ...? What do you think you're gaining by creating an object to do your rounding for you?

Comment: what would i do for the result as i does not show me a double for division I'm using the same line for division.

Comment: For double division (really float division), you need to store the result in a `float` or a `double`, which can then be converted using the first part of my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
//  Change "%2f" to "%.0f"

- (IBAction)digitAction:(id)sender {
    currentNumber = currentNumber * 10 + (double)[sender tag];
    display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", currentNumber];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need smt more like, it's conditional:

```
- (IBAction)digitAction:(id)sender {
    currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (double)[sender tag];
    double integral, fraction;
    fraction = modf(currentNumber, &integral); //This calculates the fractional part of double value
    NSString *formatString = fraction == 0.0 ? @"%.0f" : @".3f"; // Set format string according whether you have fraction or not
    display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:formatString,currentNumber];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the `stringValue` of your label or bother with `printf`-style solutions, use an `NSNumberFormatter`.  It'll give you much more control over how numbers are displayed.

Comment: %2f is much handier than a NSNumberFormatter, and it was not the cause of his problem.